# How preceding-sibling works in XPath and Python? It seems to display wrong output

Tags: python, xml

For the XML data

```
<X>
 <Y1>ABC1</Y1>
 <Y2>ABC2</Y2>
 <Z>
   <T>
     <R1>ABC3</R1>
     <R2>ABC4</R2>
   </T>
   <T>
     <R1>ABC5</R1>
     <R2>ABC6</R2>
   </T>
 </Z>
 <Y1>ABC7</Y1>
 <Y2>ABC8</Y2>
 <Z>
   <T>
     <R1>ABC3</R1>
     <R2>ABC9</R2>
   </T>
   <T>
     <R1>ABC5</R1>
     <R2>ABC9</R2>
   </T>
 </Z>
</X>
```

I wrote a sample python file like the below.

```
from lxml import etree
tree = etree.parse('test.xml')
for i in tree.xpath("//X/Z/T[R1='ABC3']/parent::*/preceding-sibling::*"):
    print(i.tag, " - ", i.text)
```

I expected output like

```
Y1  -  ABC1
Y2  -  ABC2
Y1  -  ABC1
Y2  -  ABC2
Z  -  

Y1  -  ABC7
Y2  -  ABC8
```

but received one like

```
Y1  -  ABC1
Y2  -  ABC2
Z  -  

Y1  -  ABC7
Y2  -  ABC8
```

It should print all preceding sibling. For 1st match of "R1=ABC3",it should print Y1 and Y2. For 2nd match of "R1=ABC", it should print the 5 siblings. Total 7 elements should be printed. 
What is the error here?

Comment: You mention XSLT in the question and in the tags, but your code seems to be Python and XPath with no XSLT. It's worth noting that XPath 1.0 returns "node-sets" with no defined order. In XSLT, the node-sets returned by XPath are always processed in document order, but other XPath APIs often leave this unspecified. In practice, though, delivering node-sets in document order is normal practice even if the API fails to make this explicit.

Comment: I work on different technology and just recently started to explore these so not completely aware of it. 
Thanks for pointing it out. Updated the question and tags.

Answer (score 1):

XPath 1.0 has a concept of node-sets where each `/` step eliminates duplicates based on node identity so a single XPath expression as you have used will not give a set that contains the same node twice, any duplicates are eliminated.

In XPath 2.0, while of course the `/` step operator continues to have the same duplicate elimination semantics, there is a more generalized concept of sequences using `for .. return` (`for $p in //X/Z/T[R1='ABC3']/parent::* return $p/preceding-sibling::*`) or in XPath 3.1 `!` (`//X/Z/T[R1='ABC3']/parent::*!preceding-sibling::*`) that would allow you to include duplicates, see https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/eiZQFoV.

In XPath 1.0 you would need to use several XPath evaluations in a loop of the host language (e.g. Python) or in the case of Python you could use list comprehensions `element_list = [el for parent in tree.xpath("//X/Z/T[R1='ABC3']/parent::*") for el in parent.xpath("preceding-sibling::*")]`
.

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged `xslt`, but you're not using XSLT. The expected output can be achieved using the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8"/>

<xsl:template match="/X">
    <xsl:for-each select="Z[T/R1='ABC3']">
        <xsl:for-each select="preceding-sibling::*">
            <xsl:value-of select="name()" />
            <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="text()" />
            <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As noted in the answer by Martin Honnen, it is necessary to process the preceding siblings of each matched node separately, in order to get two separate lists.

---

Note also that your expression:

```
Z/T[R1='ABC3']/parent::*
```

is unnecessarily convoluted: clearly, the parent of the matched `T` must be `Z` - so you can write simply:

```
Z[T/R1='ABC3']
```